# understanding bit twiddling hack for bit set count by lookup table

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am reading through the stanford bit twiddling hacks here:
http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetTable

For counting bits set with lookup table, I have 2 questions:
1)

```
c = BitsSetTable256[v & 0xff] + 
BitsSetTable256[(v >> 8) & 0xff] + 
BitsSetTable256[(v >> 16) & 0xff] + 
BitsSetTable256[v >> 24];
```

How is this correct. So, the table contains bits count precomputed for 256 numbers = 2^8. Now we have a 32bit number to compute bits set.  v31..v24 v23...v16 v15...v8  v7..v0

All we need to do is lookup every 8 bits in lookup table

So, it should instead be

```
c = BitsSetTable256[v & 0x0F] + 
    BitsSetTable256[v>>8 & 0x0F] + 
    BitsSetTable256[v>>16 & 0x0F] +
    BitsSetTable256[v>>24]
```

My point is that it we should be doing & with 0x0F and not FF to get to the right number in the 256 range right?

What am I missing here? : ( : (

2) Also, what does this macro mean from the same bit twiddling hacks section for bits set

```
static const unsigned char BitsSetTable256[256] = 
{
 #   define B2(n) n,     n+1,     n+1,     n+2
 #   define B4(n) B2(n), B2(n+1), B2(n+1), B2(n+2)
 #   define B6(n) B4(n), B4(n+1), B4(n+1), B4(n+2)
 B6(0), B6(1), B6(1), B6(2)
};
```

How do you expand this?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. No, that page is correct.  `0x0F` is binary `1111` (decimal 15) - four bits are set.  `0xFF` is binary `11111111` (decimal 255), 8 bits are set.
2. You can just run your preprocessor on it to see (some edits on my part to make it readable):

   ```
   static const unsigned char BitsSetTable256[256] =
   {
       0, 0 +1, 0 +1, 0 +2, 0 +1, 0 +1 +1, 0 +1 +1, 0 +1 +2, 0 +1,
       0 +1 +1, 0 +1 +1, 0 +1 +2, 0 +2, 0 +2 +1, 0 +2 +1, 0 +2 +2,
       0 +1, 0 +1 +1, 0 +1 +1, 0 +1 +2, 0 +1 +1, 0 +1 +1 +1, 0 +1 +1 +1,
       0 +1 +1 +2, 0 +1 +1, 0 +1 +1 +1, 0 +1 +1 +1, 0 +1 +1 +2, 0 +1 +2,
       0 +1 +2 +1, 0 +1 +2 +1, 0 +1 +2 +2, 0 +1, 0 +1 +1, 0 +1 +1, 0 +1 +2,
       0 +1 +1, 0 +1 +1 +1, 0 +1 +1 +1, 0 +1 +1 +2, 0 +1 +1, 0 +1 +1 +1,
       0 +1 +1 +1, 0 +1 +1 +2, 0 +1 +2, 0 +1 +2 +1, 0 +1 +2 +1, 0 +1 +2 +2,
       0 +2, 0 +2 +1, 0 +2 +1, 0 +2 +2, 0 +2 +1, 0 +2 +1 +1, 0 +2 +1 +1,
       0 +2 +1 +2, 0 +2 +1, 0 +2 +1 +1, 0 +2 +1 +1, 0 +2 +1 +2, 0 +2 +2,
       0 +2 +2 +1, 0 +2 +2 +1, 0 +2 +2 +2, 1, 1 +1, 1 +1, 1 +2, 1 +1, 1 +1 +1,
       1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +2, 1 +1, 1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +2, 1 +2, 1 +2 +1, 1 +2 +1,
       1 +2 +2, 1 +1, 1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +2, 1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +1,
       1 +1 +1 +2, 1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +2, 1 +1 +2,
       1 +1 +2 +1, 1 +1 +2 +1, 1 +1 +2 +2, 1 +1, 1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +2,
       1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +2, 1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +1,
       1 +1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +2, 1 +1 +2, 1 +1 +2 +1, 1 +1 +2 +1, 1 +1 +2 +2,
       1 +2, 1 +2 +1, 1 +2 +1, 1 +2 +2, 1 +2 +1, 1 +2 +1 +1, 1 +2 +1 +1,
       1 +2 +1 +2, 1 +2 +1, 1 +2 +1 +1, 1 +2 +1 +1, 1 +2 +1 +2, 1 +2 +2,
       1 +2 +2 +1, 1 +2 +2 +1, 1 +2 +2 +2, 1, 1 +1, 1 +1, 1 +2, 1 +1, 1 +1 +1,
       1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +2, 1 +1, 1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +2, 1 +2, 1 +2 +1,
       1 +2 +1, 1 +2 +2, 1 +1, 1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +2, 1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +1,
       1 +1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +2, 1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +2, 
       1 +1 +2, 1 +1 +2 +1, 1 +1 +2 +1, 1 +1 +2 +2, 1 +1, 1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1, 
       1 +1 +2, 1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +2, 1 +1 +1,
       1 +1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +1, 1 +1 +1 +2, 1 +1 +2, 1 +1 +2 +1, 1 +1 +2 +1,
       1 +1 +2 +2, 1 +2, 1 +2 +1, 1 +2 +1, 1 +2 +2, 1 +2 +1, 1 +2 +1 +1,
       1 +2 +1 +1, 1 +2 +1 +2, 1 +2 +1, 1 +2 +1 +1, 1 +2 +1 +1, 1 +2 +1 +2,
       1 +2 +2, 1 +2 +2 +1, 1 +2 +2 +1, 1 +2 +2 +2, 2, 2 +1, 2 +1, 2 +2, 2 +1,
       2 +1 +1, 2 +1 +1, 2 +1 +2, 2 +1, 2 +1 +1, 2 +1 +1, 2 +1 +2, 2 +2,
       2 +2 +1, 2 +2 +1, 2 +2 +2, 2 +1, 2 +1 +1, 2 +1 +1, 2 +1 +2, 2 +1 +1,
       2 +1 +1 +1, 2 +1 +1 +1, 2 +1 +1 +2, 2 +1 +1, 2 +1 +1 +1, 2 +1 +1 +1,
       2 +1 +1 +2, 2 +1 +2, 2 +1 +2 +1, 2 +1 +2 +1, 2 +1 +2 +2, 2 +1
       2 +1 +1, 2 +1 +1, 2 +1 +2, 2 +1 +1, 2 +1 +1 +1, 2 +1 +1 +1, 2 +1 +1 +2,
       2 +1 +1, 2 +1 +1 +1, 2 +1 +1 +1, 2 +1 +1 +2, 2 +1 +2, 2 +1 +2 +1,
       2 +1 +2 +1, 2 +1 +2 +2, 2 +2, 2 +2 +1, 2 +2 +1, 2 +2 +2, 2 +2 +1,
       2 +2 +1 +1, 2 +2 +1 +1, 2 +2 +1 +2, 2 +2 +1, 2 +2 +1 +1, 2 +2 +1 +1,
       2 +2 +1 +2, 2 +2 +2, 2 +2 +2 +1, 2 +2 +2 +1, 2 +2 +2 +2
   };
   ```